# Synergy keeps logging non-stop

Tags: 16.04, memory-usage, logging, synergy

i've been using synergy to use my desaktop's mouse &keyboard on my laptop when home. Now, it's been working really well for me, except that I've realized that the instance on my desktop will eat up unreasonably much memory over time. I've realized that in the log windows on the bottom, it keeps saying:

```
2018-11-03T13:47:51 NOTE: accepted client connection
    /build/synergy-CUL4K_/synergy-1.6.2/src/lib/server/ClientListener.cpp,137
2018-11-03T13:47:51 NOTE: disconnecting client "ron-notebook"
    /build/synergy-CUL4K_/synergy-1.6.2/src/lib/server/Server.cpp,2123
2018-11-03T13:47:51 WARNING: a client with name "ron-notebook" is already connected
    /build/synergy-CUL4K_/synergy-1.6.2/src/lib/server/Server.cpp,326
2018-11-03T13:47:51 NOTE: client "ron-notebook" has disconnected
    /build/synergy-CUL4K_/synergy-1.6.2/src/lib/server/ClientProxy1_0.cpp,213
2018-11-03T13:47:52 NOTE: accepted client connection
    /build/synergy-CUL4K_/synergy-1.6.2/src/lib/server/ClientListener.cpp,137
2018-11-03T13:47:52 NOTE: disconnecting client "ron-notebook"
    /build/synergy-CUL4K_/synergy-1.6.2/src/lib/server/Server.cpp,2123
2018-11-03T13:47:52 WARNING: a client with name "ron-notebook" is already connected
    /build/synergy-CUL4K_/synergy-1.6.2/src/lib/server/Server.cpp,326
2018-11-03T13:47:52 NOTE: client "ron-notebook" has disconnected
    /build/synergy-CUL4K_/synergy-1.6.2/src/lib/server/ClientProxy1_0.cpp,213
```

over and over again, until (I assume) a good portion of memory is eaten up and I actually kill and relaunch the instance... any idea why this is and how/if I can resolve this problem? I've installed synergy from the ubuntu repos

Answer (score 0):

I went to `Edit`->`Settings` and set the `Logging level` in the box **Logging** to `Error`, hit `OK` and then `Apply` which caused the continuous logging to stop!